# How to deploy from bitbucket pipelines with sftp and key?

Tags: continuous-integration, bitbucket, sftp, continuous-deployment, bitbucket-pipelines

Im trying to use BitBucket Pipelines to push to a remote server using `git-ftp` and `sftp`. am using amazon Linux 2

Here is my bitbucket-pipelines.yml;

```
image: madshansen/docker-git-ftp:latest

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script:
          - apt-get update
          - apt-get -qq install git-ftp
          - git ftp push --user $FTP_USERNAME "sftp://servername.domain.com/var/www/html/dev.videommerce.com/"
```

Unfortunately, I am getting the following error

```
fatal: Remote host not set.
```

Note: I have added key and all variables as per documentation.

What is wrong with my code?